# Python: How to filter out rows that are between the dates of other rows with the same ID

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe with rows that I'd like to filter out based on the dates of similar entries. Basically I want to exclude the rows with the start date in between the start and end date of columns with the same ID.

```
Current Output:
ID       Start Date       End Date
A        2019-1-1         2019-1-10
B        2019-1-1         2019-1-8
A        2019-1-2         2019-1-11
A        2019-1-3         2019-1-12
B        2019-1-7         2019-1-15
A        2019-1-12        2019-1-19
A        2019-1-20        2019-1-22

Desired Output:
ID       Start Date       End Date
A        2019-1-1         2019-1-10
B        2019-1-1         2019-1-8
A        2019-1-12        2019-1-19
A        2019-1-20        2019-1-22
```

Comment: where is 2019-1-11

Comment: Can't think of anything except a for loop.